# Delete rows from DataTable at once without loop where a column has Null value

Tags: c#, datatable, delete-row, import-from-excel

I'm populating a DataTable object from an Excel worksheet.  I'm not counting on the user entering data correctly, and I'd like to delete rows that have a null value in column A.  I've searched around quite a bit, and it looks like everyone is doing this with a for loop.  Here's the problem: 757,000 rows.  If data is not formatted properly that DataTable gets filled up with Excel's max of 1048575.  I don't need to check each value individually.  In SQL server you can write:

`DELETE table
 WHERE columnA IS NULL`

I considered excluding nulls on the DataTable fill, but I couldn't get this to work reliably as I don't know the name of column A until it's in the DataTable and sometimes the column name has a `\n` character in the middle which throws syntax errors.

How can I accomplish the same sort of thing without a loop?

Comment: Do you want to delete the rows form the source workbook or just not show them in the datatable?  How are you reading from excel?

Comment: can you not implement the `Select()` Method of the DataTable to filter down and perhaps populate a DataTable from there..? also `IN SQL Server` Your syntax is incorrect.. it's `DELETE [FROM TABLE NAME] WHERE Clause`

Comment: @DStanley really I just want them to not be in the datatable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about creating a new, clean DataTable from your first one?

```
DataTable t = new DataTable(); //actually your existing one with bad records
DataTable newTable = t.Select().Where(x => !x.IsNull(0)).CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use Linq...

```
var newData = (from d in DataTable //this would be your datatable. 
              where d.columnA != NULL
              select d.*).CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
```

Then just use your newData variable, which holds your newly populated datatable.